# Cannot append constant (struct) type to array

Tags: arrays, constants, d

In one struct, Shape I have a function:

```
...
import graphics.line;

struct Shape {
    Line[] lines;

    void addLine(Line l) {
        lines ~= l;
    }
}
```

Line is also a struct, but when I put "`in Line l`" as the argument declaration for `addLine()`,
the compiler bugs out with:

> shape.d(12): Error: cannot append type
>   const(Line) to type Line[]

The weird thing is I have a similar piece of code in another module, and it works... So my question is, why is the compiler not happy with it in this case?

Answer (score 12):

Basically, whether this works depends on what members your struct has. The `in` 
storage class is equivalent to `const scope`. So, writing 
`void addLine(in Line l)` means that `l` is const. And since `const` is 
transitive, all `Line l` struct members are `const`, too.

The `Shape` member `Line[] lines` is however not `const`. So, you are trying to
append a `const Line l` to something that is not `const`. Whether this is 
possible depends on the types of all members of the `struct Line l`. If *all* 
members of `line` have value (copy) semantics, this appending (which is an 
assignment) is possible. If any one member has (some) reference semantics (e.g. 
a pointer gets copied), this appending is no longer possible. Otherwise, you 
could give a `const Line lc` into `addLines`, but would get a non-const member 
of `lines`. Through this, you could change the value with reference semantics,
changing the value of the original `lc` indirectly, too, thereby violating the
`const` guarantee, namely the transitivity of `const` in D.

Example:

```
class C { }

struct Line {
    int i;
    // int* p;               // if you uncomment this, addLine fails
    // C c;                  // if you uncomment this, addLine fails
}

struct Shape { 
    Line[] lines;
    void addLine(in Line l) { lines ~= l; }
}

void main() { }
```

**Edit:** BTW, another way to make it work is to change `Line[] lines;` to `const(Line)[] lines;`. Than the array contains only `const` elements, and the appending of a `const l` in `addLine` is possible.